# How do I manage how many revisions snapd keeps of an application?

Tags: package-management, snap

So I installed vlc daily built snap package.

It's working great, no problems there. However I noticed that after upgrade the system has 2 versions of vlc (7 and 9). That can be seen when browsing /snap/vlc/ directory and using system monitor.

This is also the case with other snaps. Is there a way to automatically delete older versions of snaps? Or do I just delete them using plain "rm" command? Is it safe to delete them that way?

Answer (score 20):

For **Ubuntu 20.04 and newer**, snapd will automatically retain **two** revisions (usually current plus one older) by default, and will delete older.

For **Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier**, snapd will automatically retain **three** revisions (usually current plus two older) by default, and will delete older.

In mid-2018, [snapd was updated](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/configure-number-of-old-revisions-to-keep/2337) so that the number of revisions is configurable (though never less than 2).

Use the command:

`snap set system refresh.retain=N`

N cannot be less than two.

Comment: This superuser answer was extremely helpful to purge all older snap versions: https://superuser.com/questions/1310825/how-to-remove-old-version-of-installed-snaps

Comment: Why can't we set it to be 1?

Comment: @nog it's fundamental to the way snap packages work. Older version(s) retained in case the newer is broken.

Answer (score 5):

In speaking with Ubuntu developers, the current default is to keep three prior versions of a snap so that you can roll-back to a prior version if needed. This default setting is not configurable.

You can use the command `snap remove --revision=<an old one> snapname` to remove an older revision of a snap.

They are considering whether to have only the current snap mounted as a loop filesystem, but I don't know the status of that.

Answer (score 2):

*[Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803275/system-keeps-older-snap-packages#comment1212783_803275) from [doug](https://askubuntu.com/users/27773/doug), somewhat extended*:

`/snap/*` is read-only and snaps are mounted there. The reason for this is that `snapd` allows you to roll back to an older version of a given snap, that's why it keeps multiple versions. Calling `snap remove` will remove them all from the system again. There is a r/w location for snaps, but that's unrelated. https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/garbage needs an update, but it explains the general concept.

Rolling back is done using `snap revert`:

> daniel@daydream:~$ snap revert --help
>   Usage:
>     snap [OPTIONS] revert []
>
> The revert command reverts the given snap to its state before the
>   latest refresh. This will reactivate the previous snap revision, and
>   will use the original data that was associated with that revision,
>   discarding any data changes that were done by the latest revision. As
>   an exception, data which the snap explicitly chooses to share across
>   revisions is not touched by the revert process.
>
> Application Options:
>         --version     print the version and exit
>
> Help Options:   -h, --help        Show this help message
>   daniel@daydream:~$