# Is it safe to delete /var/lib/snapd/snapshots?

Tags: 18.04, snap, disk-usage, storage, snapshot

I had to reinstall Spotify because of an issue, which is now resolved but something else came up. I was notified that my root partition was filling up and I realised that in `/var/lib/snapd/snapshots`, there is a file called `16_spotify_1.1.42.622.gbd112320-37_42.zip` which is 3.7Gb large. I assume that that is definitely not normal. Is there a way to remove this file?

Comment: Regarding the suggestion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/803275/how-do-i-manage-how-many-revisions-snapd-keeps-of-an-application


Partly. I still don't understand why it is taking up so much space. Other snapshots of much larger programs with much higher revision numbers take up less than 200Mb. But I used snap to remove it and limited the maximum revision number. So thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Spotify's streaming cache can get quite large, locally, especially if using the download-offline feature; something to bare in mind. – Happens also on mobile, where local free space is more a concern.

Comment: snap sucks, just get rid of it and use plain apt or aptitude

Answer (score 14):

You probably can just delete these archive files without negative side effects, but the user exposed approach to delete snapshots is using the `snap forget` command.

- List the saved snapshots with the command `snap saved`
- Remove a snapshot with the command `snap forget #` where `#` stands for the set number (first column in the output of the list).

Snapshots that are automatically created (i.e., not actively by you through a `snap save` command) are automatically deleted after 31 days.

Specifically for Spotify: these snapshots contain user configuration data. In the case of Spotify, this might include locally buffered or downloaded music. This can explain the very large size.